# Convert list op tuples into two lists of one-elemnt tuple

Tags: haskell

In haskell I'm trying to acheive to convert a list like [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
into two lists: [1,3,5] and [2,4,6] using **a recursive function only**

I tried this so far, but it doesn't work

```
unpair :: [(a,b)] -> ([a], [b])
unpair [] = []   
unpair ((x,y):xs) = x : unpair(xs) y : unpair (xs)
```

however, when I only try to make a list of the first value in the tuples, it does work:

```
unpair [] = []  
unpair ((x,y):xs) = x : unpair(xs)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `unpair` returns a _pair_, not a list. Hence, both your examples are wrong. Use `case .. of (x,y) -> ` or `let (x,y)=... in` to access the components of a pair.

Answer (score 4):

The type of `unpair xs` is `([a], [b])`, so you can't append an element to it like to a list. But you can use `let` statement to pattern-match the result from `unpair xs`, then construct the tuple with the new head element added to each.

I won't quote the actual answer because this looks like home work.

---

The reason the second implementation works is because in that one the type of `unpair` is `[(a,b)]->[a]`.